# 11.10 file extension

Tags: 11.10, files, deb

what file extensions does ubuntu 11.10 use ?
i am trying to install google chrome.
in google chrome site there are two types of files available for Ubuntu ".deb" and ".rpm"
i downloaded both, but neither one works...

Answer (score 3):

.rpm files (Red Hat Package Manager) are for Red Hat based Linux versions like Fedora and CentOS.  Ubuntu is a Debian based version of Linux, so you will want the .deb file.

Once you are done with your download, you can install Chrome by double-clicking on the .deb file or by executing the following command via terminal.

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Note, that this command assumes the following:

- You have changed to the directory which contains the .deb file.
- The name of the Chrome download file is "google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb"